# Using list comprehension to generate various lists of numbers: why comparisons work?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm still new to python. Some of the exercises I'm working on are things like 'return a list of integers up to but less than n' or 'return a list of odd (or even) integers up to but less than n', etc.

Seems reasonably straight-forward, and I was able to understand how to make a short function that does these things. For example, for generating a list of odd numbers...

```
def odds(n)
    return [i for i in range(n) if (i % 2 == 1)]
```

... works just fine.

But the suggested solution was:

```
def odds(n)
    return [i for i in range(n) if i % 2]
```

This returns the same thing. But I don't understand the 'if i % 2' at the end. How can this work when we haven't clarified what the 'i % 2' test needs to evaluate to???

Answer (score 0):

because in python booleans are just integers, 0 is False and any other number is True
So when you say `if i % 2` the same as if you say `if i % 2 != 0`, if it equals 0 then it's false and it won't do anything, but if it's anything other than false `0` it will push `i` to the list

EDIT:
try to do something like this:

```
if 1:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Then try it with 0 and you'll see the difference.

Comment: So can I understand it as basically that 'if i % 2' defaults to testing whether it is True?

Comment: Yes, expressions that require a boolean, like "if" will essentially automatically wrap the given object in bool().

Comment: @Dragon-Ash Yes, it's just testing if it's anything other than 0 and if it is, then it'll be true otherwise it's false

Comment: @Dragon-Ash Let's assume that i is 5, so 5 % 2 = 1 "in int" which is True, but if it's an even number like 4 then it'll be 0 because 4 % 2 = 0 so it's False